# Find the eventually periodic points of the function $f(x)=\lvert x-1 \rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, harmonic-analysis, chaos-theory

Let $\emptyset\neq X\supset A$,  $f:A\rightarrow X$, 
a point $x\in A$ is **eventually periodic point**  of $f$, if :
$$\exists n_0\in\mathbb N \exists N\in\mathbb N: f^{n+N}(x)=f^n(x) \quad \forall n\ge n_0.$$

Note: $f^n(x) := \underbrace{f\circ f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{ \text{$n$ times }}(x).$

---

I don't  quite understand the following proof.

$$\text{Let } f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R : f(x)= \lvert x-1\rvert,$$
$$f(0)=1,f(1)=0\implies 0 \text{ and } 1 \text{ are periodic points of $f$.}$$
$$f(-1)=2, f(-k)=k+1, f(k)=k-1 ,\forall k\ge 2,k\text{ integer.} \implies $$
$$\implies \text{every integer point is eventually periodic point of $f$ .}$$

I understand the part that $1$ and $-1$ are periodic points, but im a bit confused about the rest of the proof.

Comment: Also, $x\in[0,1] \implies f^2(x)=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following diagram:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&&&& -1 && -2 && -3 && -4 & \cdots \\
&&&& \downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow \\
0 & \longleftrightarrow & 1 & \longleftarrow & 2 & \longleftarrow & 3 & \longleftarrow & 4 & \longleftarrow & 5 & \longleftarrow & \cdots
\end{matrix}
$$

If $f$ is repeatedly applied to an integer $k$, we eventually end reach $1$. From that point, the sequence $f^n(k)$ becomes periodic: 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...

For a formal proof, because $1$ is eventually periodic and $f(k)=k-1$ for positive $k$, it follows by induction that all positive integers are eventually periodic.

From $f(-k) = k+1$ for positive $k$ it then also follows immediately that all negative integers are eventually periodic.